# Android sending data to class from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

i'm creating some Android app, where user add his data, and app will work with it. To work i need to write data to `SomeClass.kt`, from `MainActivity.kt`. I tried to do it with Intent, but it give null to me (I guess, if Intent dont get startActivity option, it will not send "putExtra" data. Or may be i write getIntent wrong, but it give data in second activity. So, the question is: How i can send data from MainActivity to SomeClassFile.kt? My codes :

**MainActivity.kt**:

```
...
val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
val sname = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPassword)

val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, DataClass::class.java)
val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("login", name.toString())
            bundle.putString("email", sname)
            bundle.putString("test", "hello world")
            myIntent.putExtra("MyPackage", bundle)

...
```

**DataClass.kt**:

```
class DataClass {

    val callerIntent = intent // <-- Error is here, 'Unresolved reference: intent'
    val packageFromCaller = callerIntent.getBundleExtra("MyPackage")
    val contact = packageFromCaller!!.getString("login")
    val email = packageFromCaller!!.getString("email")
    val test = packageFromCaller!!.getString("test")

}
```

In another Activity, using same code as in `DataClass.kt` i got my text (two from EditText and "Hello world!")

Also, i can write my information to .txt file and try to get data in class from this .txt file, but when i try to open it in "class" file, i got an error with ''Unresolved reference: openFileInput''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need activity to get instance of "intent", but since you are using separate class you can go with this -

1. `class DataClass(private val activity: WeakReference<Activity>) { val callerIntent get() = activity.get()?.intent }`

to make object of DataClass -

```
val dataClassX = DataClass(WeakReference(this@YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME))
```

where "this" is reference of your activity / or use getActivity() in fragments.

Comment: Well, thank you, I guess it will help, will check in Friday

Comment: I got an error "Unresolved reference: intent" in DataClass. Again :(

Comment: can u share your code

Comment: I apologise , I have edited the example and tested it's working now , u can use above example

Comment: Thank you, i used to read from .txt now. When i using intent, i cant give data to val in class, i guess it is problem from lack of experience in development. However, thank you, it really works

Comment: no problem, just don't lose hope and stay dedicated to it, at first we all were like this. you will get through it , all the very best